# Call to action button CSS modification

Tags: css

I have a sales page here: http://salesautopilot.s3.amazonaws.com/newsletter/letter/nl57825/ns103923/subscribe.html

My problem is when I view the site on mobile, the text in the blue call to action button overflows the button.

How should I modify the button's CSS so it won't?

I think this is the part of the CSS code that defines the button:

```
.mmform-container div.submitcontainer a.submitbutton,.mmform-container button.mmform-event-button,.mmform-container div.submitcontainer button.submitbutton {
    background-color: #208dda;  
    border: none;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 0.8px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px 0;
    /*width: 70%;*/
    min-height: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 70%;
}
```

Thank you guys
David

Comment: Please add the relevant "*[mcve]*" code to your question, including the HTML don't just link to it; that way your question is self-contained and makes sense, and is useful, to future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the last word is too long that with fixed font size and width it doesn't fit in one line. You could use `word-wrap: break-word;` to break that word, but then it's kinda ugly. 
Imo best scenario would be to either:

- reduce the text in the button (to just 'register') or
- decrease the font size for smaller screens. For that you can use [CSS media query](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

Answer (score -1):

if you just edit that way :

```
@media (max-width: 640px){
    .submitcontainer a{
        width:100%!important;
    }
```

Comment: it doesn't fix the problem

Comment: if it is why -1 ? We can investigate the problem and fine the solution without being bad